# horizontal scrolling for Div using Protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to scroll to the right, but nothing helps

I have tried

```js
await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)',element.getWebElement())
```

but it's not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let location = await $element.getLocation();

await browser.executeScript(
  `
    window.scroll(
      ${location.x},${location.y}
    );
  `
)
```

I haven't tested but the approach should work

Answer (score 0):

I use mouseMove to scroll till the end of page and it works perfectly fine for me, I think same should work for horizontal scroll also.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css("provide element in the right most corner"))).perform();
```